Commutators and unitriangular matrices
Suppose $K$ is any field. I want to show that $[\mathbf{UT}^r_n(K), \mathbf{UT}^s_n(K)]=\mathbf{UT}^{r+s}_n(K)$, using the identity $[t_{ik}(\alpha), t_{kj}(\beta)]=t_{ij}(\alpha\beta)$, where $t_{ij}(\alpha)$ is the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix with $\alpha$ in the $(i,j)$-entry. I understand that the RHS is included in the LHS, since we can express any of its generators $t_{ij}(\alpha)$ with $j-i\geq r+s$ as
$$t_{ij}(\alpha 1)=[t_{ik}(\alpha), t_{kj}(1)]$$
where $k$ is such that $k-i\geq r$ and $j-k \geq s$. I'm stuck now - I don't know how to use the above formula to say anything going from left to right. Is there a simple way like this to proceed?
